# "Access to the file path is denied"

Tags: vb.net

Whenever my application attempts to copy a file into C:\Users\???\AppData\Local, I get "Access to the file path is denied" Even when I'm running the app with admin it is still not working, can anybody help out?

Comment: Those users folders have weird permissions on them (I have run into the same problem). I would avoid trying to write to them if you can avoid it. +1 for a question I would be interested to know the answer to myself.

Comment: It's not the end of the world if I can't copy it directly to there, but I would still be interesed in knowing the reason why it's happening. @LordTakkera

Comment: Are you hard coding the path, or are you obtaining it by using an appropriate call to [`Enivornment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I'm using `Envirornment.GetFolderPath`, in this case it's this: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 3):

You'll get a `Access to the path '...' is denied` error if the folder is flagged `ReadOnly`. You could try to remove this flag prior to copying the file.

```
Dim info As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\???\AppData\Local")

If (info.Exists AndAlso ((info.Attributes And FileAttributes.[ReadOnly]) = FileAttributes.[ReadOnly])) Then
    info.Attributes = (info.Attributes Xor FileAttributes.[ReadOnly])
End If
```

**Update**

I did a google search and found these link which seems interesting:

- [Folder Access Denied for Windows 7 Administrator](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/folder-access-denied-for-windows-7-administrator/c506c825-a22f-4aff-9a75-9b83bd14ff44)
- [Junction Points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968829%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> "Those are junction points : hidden, protected operating system files that are not meant to be accessed by users. Each one points to a user-accessible folder:"

- *Application Data:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming
- *Cookies:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
- *History:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History
- *Local Settings:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Local
- *My Documents:* C:\Users{user name}\Documents
- *NetHood:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
- *PrintHood:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
- *Recent:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
- *SendTo:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
- *Start Menu:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
- *Templates:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Roaming
- *Temporary Internet Files:* C:\Users{user name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files

> "These junction points can be identified as follows:"

- They have the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM file attributes set.
- They also have their access control lists (ACLs) set to deny read access to everyone.

**So...**

I don't know if this is recommended, will work or throw an error, but you could try to remove these flags:

```
info.Attributes = (attributes Xor (FileAttributes.ReparsePoint Or FileAttributes.Hidden Or FileAttributes.System))
```

And add then back afterwards:

```
info.Attributes = (attributes Or (FileAttributes.ReparsePoint Or FileAttributes.Hidden Or FileAttributes.System))
```

Comment: "FileAttributes" Is not declared.

Comment: The `FileAttributes` enumeration are located in `System.IO`. Add `Imports System.IO` at the top of your code page.

Comment: I tried your method but to no avail, It's strange because I've done this before to other locations such as the C:\ drive with no issues, it's only with the Local folder that I'm facing problems. @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå

Comment: @LOLZguy712 I did some research, please check my edit.

Comment: What is "attributes"?

Comment: @Brady [File attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_attribute) are metadata that define file system behavior.